# How do I only make a printf statement appear if the statement is true?

Tags: c, variables, printf, statements

I'm making a shipping calculator, if the package weighs over 50 pounds were unable to ship the package. I want to make a statement appear only if the package weighs more than 50 pounds, but it appears no matter what.

I tried it as an else statement, if statement, and if else statement.

```
main(){
    double distance, weight, weightCharges, shippingCharge, distanceCharge, unableToShip;
    printf ("Enter the weight of the package:\n");
    scanf ("%lf", &weight);
    printf ("Enter the distance your package needs to go: \n");
    scanf ("%lf", &distance);

    if (weight <= 10)
        weightCharges = weight * 3.00;
        else
            if (weight <= 50)
                weightCharges = weight * 5.00;
            else (weight > 50);
        weightCharges= 0;
    if (distance > 1000)
        distanceCharge = weightCharges + 10;
    shippingCharge = weightCharges + distanceCharge;
    unableToShip = weight > 50;

    printf ("Your total cost is: %.2lf \n", shippingCharge);
    printf ("We're unable to ship your package \n", unableToShip);

}
```

I expect the second printf to only appear if we cannot ship their package, but it appears no matter what.

Comment: Identation is used for readability in C/C++, not for control flow.  Add braces.

Comment: Btw it would make more sense to declare `unableToShip` to be of type `bool` rather than of type `double`, since the only values you want to express with it are `true` or `false`.

Comment: I'm still in the beginning of my introduction to C in my computer programming class so we haven't learned that yet unfortunately. But thank you for the advice! I figured it out.

Comment: Don't you get some warning in this line `else (weight > 50)`? Something like "expression with no effect"? Your `weightCharges` will always be 0.

Comment: Are you asking about C or C++?  These are very different languages, and although it is possible to write programs which do the same in both, the intersection is poor C++ and poor C.

Answer (score 3):

`if` works the same way here as it does anywhere else:

```
if (unableToShip) 
  printf ("We're unable to ship your package\n");
```

Answer (score 3):

Did you try to put some if-else statements?

```
int main()
{
    double distance, weight, weightCharges, shippingCharge, distanceCharge; // no need for unableToShip;
    printf ("Enter the weight of the package:\n");
    scanf ("%lf", &weight);
    printf ("Enter the distance your package needs to go: \n");
    scanf ("%lf", &distance);

    if (weight <= 10)
        weightCharges = weight * 3.00;
        else
            if (weight <= 50)
                weightCharges = weight * 5.00;
            else (weight > 50);
        weightCharges= 0;
    if (distance > 1000)
        distanceCharge = weightCharges + 10;
    shippingCharge = weightCharges + distanceCharge;
    //unableToShip = ;

    printf ("Your total cost is: %.2lf \n", shippingCharge);
    if(weight > 50)
    printf ("We're unable to ship your package \n");

}
```

Answer (score 1):

First off, `unableToShip` should be of type `int` or `bool` (if you are using a compiler that is up-to-date and supports `<stdbool.h>`). `double` doesn't really work well for this sort of thing.

Secondly, even if `unableToShip` were a correct type for a boolean condtion, passing as an argument to `printf` does not make `printf` work conditionally. That makes it part of the formatted output, if you had a format string to accept it. What you need to have is `if (unableToShip)` followed by the `printf` statement.

Third, if you are printing a string that does not contain any formatting and ends in a new line, you should use `puts` instead of `printf`.

Comment: Yeah, well i'm only on my 4th assignment in my Introductory to Computer Programming class so "misunderstanding" is an understatement.

Answer (score 0):

```
int main(){
    double distance, weight, weightCharges, shippingCharge, distanceCharge, unableToShip;
    printf ("Enter the weight of the package:\n");
    scanf ("%lf", &weight);
    printf ("Enter the distance your package needs to go: \n");
    scanf ("%lf", &distance);

    if (weight <= 20)
        weightCharges = weight * 5.00;
        else
            if (weight <= 100)
                weightCharges = weight * 10.00;
            else (weight > 100);
        weightCharges= 0;
    if (distance > 1000)
        distanceCharge = weightCharges + 20;
    shippingCharge = weightCharges + distanceCharge;
    unableToShip = weight > 100;

    printf ("Your total cost is: %.2lf \n", shippingCharge);
    printf ("We're unable to ship your package \n", unableToShip);

}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. You could add what you have changed to fix the problem. Your code should trigger some warnings in the compiler. Your code also does not solve the issue. The last output is done without taking care about any condition.

Comment: Why the upvotes? The question is not answered at all. The code does not solve the problem and introduces undefined behaviour.

Comment: You could add what you have changed to fix the problem. Your code should trigger some warnings in the compiler.

Comment: What ist the purpose of responding with a partial copy of my comment without any additional text? If there is a message, I don't get it.